Regularization of claw-free graphs
Let $G$ be a claw-free graph (containing no induced subgraph isomorphic to $S_4$) with $\Delta(G)) = k$ where $k$ is a constant with respect to $|V(G)|$. Is it always possible to regularize the graph with the operations:

Addition of vertices disjoint to $G$.
Arbitrary addition of edges

in such a way that if $G'$ is the resultant $k'$-regular graph, $G'$ is also claw-free and $k'$ is also independent of $|V(G)|$, $|V(G')|$?

It is probably safe to start with simple subclasses of claw-free graphs. Line-graphs are easy. Can you do circular interval graphs ? I don't see how.

Can I choose any k'>k? If the intermediate steps don't have to be claw-free, then how about just duplicating vertices? If intermediate steps have to be claw-free, a disjoint union of many icosahedrons might be a counterexample? For a large connected graph with constant degree, the claw-free structure theorem probably becomes simpler, closer to just circular interval graph, though that's likely a lot of work. Adding vertices doesn't seem to help, but it might still be true with only adding edges: enlarge each interval somehow, or maybe connect vertices that were originally at distance two.
